# Merging csv files but removing last row and multiple columns

Tags: csv, batch-file, cmd, merge

My initial issue was merging multiple csv's into one, removing the first couple of rows each (in my case 5) and all blank ones. I was able to find the following solution:

```
@echo off
>Output.csv(
    for %%f in (*.csv) do (
        for /f "delims=" %%l in ('more +5 %%f') do (
            echo %%f,%%l
        )
    )
)
```

I haven't been able to rewrite the code to erase the last line of each file and erase a couple of columns from the output.csv file yet (or the individual ones).

This is an example of a csv file:

```
Timecard Report
06/12/2017 - 06/12/2017
Departments : All_Departments-TOTAL HOURS

EMPLOYEE NAME,EMPLOYEE PAYROLL ID,FIRST NAME,LAST NAME,DEPARTMENT NAME,REG,REG Pay,OT1 Hours,OT1 Pay,OT2 Hours,OT2 Pay,VAC Hours,VAC Pay,HOL Hours,HOL Pay,SIC Hours,SIC Pay,OTH Hours,OTH Pay,TOTAL Hours,Total Pay 
Oc Br,999,Oc,Br,Fulfillment,8.00,114.8,.53,11.41,,,,,,,,,,,8.53,126.21 
Brat Hat,3423,Brat,Hat,Logistics Admin,5.42,75.88,,,,,,,,,,,,,5.42,75.88 
Tod Vindo,,Tod,Vindo,Logistics Admin,8.00,128,1.18,28.32,,,,,,,,,,,9.18,156.32 

TOTAL,,,,,73.53,1143.25,3.30,73.23,,,,,,,,,,,76.83,1216.48
```

Anyone an idea?

Comment: The picture doesn't help much as it doesn't show the real csv file or at least a neutralized version if it contains confidential information. And plaese not a picture but copied and pasted text. I slowly begin to feel wasting my time.

Comment: I am new here, sorry about that. Makes total sense of course to paste text. Copied you the altered content of a file.

Comment: Which columns do you want to keep? First 9 and last 2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

New powershell answer. This script :

```
$KeepCols = @(
"EMPLOYEE NAME",
"EMPLOYEE PAYROLL ID",
"FIRST NAME",
"LAST NAME",
"DEPARTMENT NAME",
"REG",
"REG Pay",
"OT1 Hours",
"OT1 Pay",
"TOTAL Hours",
"Total Pay ")

Get-ChildItem '*.csv' -Exclude '*_dq.csv'|
  ForEach-Object {
    $fn=$_.Fullname
    "Processing $fn"
    (Get-Content $fn) | Select-Object -Skip 4 | ConvertFrom-Csv|
    Where-Object "EMPLOYEE NAME" -ne "TOTAL"|
    Select-Object -Property $KeepCols|
      Export-Csv -path ($fn.replace('.csv','_dq.csv')) -NoType
  }
```

Will produce this output from your above sample:

```
"EMPLOYEE NAME","EMPLOYEE PAYROLL ID","FIRST NAME","LAST NAME","DEPARTMENT NAME","REG","REG Pay","OT1 Hours","OT1 Pay","TOTAL Hours","Total Pay "
"Oc Br","999","Oc","Br","Fulfillment","8.00","114.8",".53","11.41","8.53","126.21 "
"Brat Hat","3423","Brat","Hat","Logistics Admin","5.42","75.88","","","5.42","75.88 "
"Tod Vindo","","Tod","Vindo","Logistics Admin","8.00","128","1.18","28.32","9.18","156.32 "
```

So the steps

- process all `.csv` files exclude the ones with trailing `_dq` and save with `_dq` appended
- strip 4 lines
- remove unwanted columns
- properly quote fields
- remove the last `TOTAL` line

Are done. What still is to do:

- Merge the files (without, now only one, header line)
- Check if the last column really has a trailing space.

Comment: So cool, exactly what I needed. What I did now was saving this as a Powershell script, adding before the inital .bat the code at the end, and naming both, the Powershell script and .bat, the same. Works like a charm. Thanks so much! >> @ECHO OFF
PowerShell.exe -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command "& '%~dpn0.ps1'"
PAUSE

Comment: Upvoted your answers but it won't show since I have less than 15 reputations. I will make sure to upvote it later on. Again, much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

IMO merging normally means adding columns, not appending/concatenating to the end.  Instead of more you could have used `"skip=5 delims="`
To remove the last line you could store the actual line in a var and print the previous one. As this is inside a (code block) you need [DelayedExpansion](https://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html) then (what may remove exclamation marks in your csv).

To remove columns you will need to specify a delimiter and a matching tokens parameter to omit the columns you don't want.
Provided the "delims=," and you want to strip columns 2 and 5 from 6

```
@echo off&SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
(   for %%f in (*.csv) do (
        Set "last="
        for /f "tokens=1,3-4,6 delims=," %%A in ('more +5 %%f') do (
            if defined last echo %%f,!last!
            Set "last=%%A,%%B,%%C,%%D"
        )
    )
) >Output.csv
```

My sample output:

```
Output.csv


FatTwin1.csv,1,3,4,6
FatTwin2.csv,13,15,16,18
```

To overcome the problem with empty fields you can `normalize` the csv files by im-/exporting them with powershell what will double quote all fields.

This cmd line will invoke powershell to import-csv and export-csv all csv files in the current folder and store with an appended `_dq` to the name. This requires the files to have a header with unique column names.

```
Powershell -NonI -NoP -Com "gci *.csv -excl '*_dq.csv'|%{$fn=$_.Fullname;(import-csv $fn )|export-csv -path ($fn.replace('.csv','_dq.csv')) -notype}"
```

Comment: Thanks for your fast help. I tried both codes by pasting them into a .bat file, but neither seem to work. No Output.csv file either. Is there a way to troubleshoot this from my end?

Comment: Problem was a missing space between the redirection and the opening parenthesis I took over from your code. Changed.

Comment: Ah, ok. The code runs and works with one exception now: E.g.
"for /f "tokens=1-2,5-9,12-13,17-19,21 delims=," %%A in ('more +5 %%f') do" outputs only columns 1-2,5,6. At first I thought that might have to do with some columns being empty, but that's not the case for columns 7 and 8 in this case.

Comment: The batch is currently prepared for a total of 4 columns, to add more append variables `,%%E,%%F....`

Comment: Empty columns are a problem because adjoining delimiters are counted as one.

Comment: Just tested it and you're of course correct. The algorithm disregards all columns to the right of the first empty one. The problem is, the csv files I am working with tracks labor. Columns like "overtime" change and are often just empty. This restriction unfortunately defeats the purpose of merging the data automatically. Is there a way around this issue? Btw.: Thanks so much for bearing with me.

Comment: An easy way around is to import and export the csv with powershell, this puts double quotes around each field thus eliminating empty fields. I'll take a look into it tomorrow.

Comment: 1|Timecard Report                    
2|06/12/2017 - 06/12/2017                    
3|Departments : All_Departments-TOTAL HOURS                    
4|                    
5|EMPLOYEE NAME          EMPLOYEE PAYROLL      FIRST NAME ...

Comment: ^ This is pretty much how each file looks like. The numbers indicate the rows. These files have neither unique headers nor headers at all before I cut off the first 4 rows. I tried to run the command in a .bat file and within the command prompt, but it got stuck in an endless loop.

Comment: Sorry, I can't follow. If this is a sample of your csv file, please edit the question to include it. And it's over time to do so.